# swing syntax highlighter

Tags: java, swing

I need some advice on creating a syntax highligher for java application using swing. The application should allow to edit a file and highlight syntax.

I don't know the swing library, what should I look for?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I use [RSyntaxTextArea](https://github.com/bobbylight/RSyntaxTextArea) and it works well.

Answer (score 2):

[JSyntaxPane](http://code.google.com/p/jsyntaxpane/) is quite active and supports a lot of languages (+ a friendly license).

Answer (score 1):

You could build on [JEditorPane](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html), but it might be easier to use the [jedit syntax](http://syntax.jedit.org/) bean.

Comment: Haha you beat me to it with that jEdit thought. I was about to suggest using jEdit itself: http://www.jedit.org/api/index.html

Comment: (the OP), just for the record, JEditorPane does *not* support direct syntax highlighting: you'll need to parse the Java source file yourself and then highlight the tokens (no trivial task!).